# Too fast checking local ports with python socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

This code example is given in the book "CPython Internals".

```py
from queue import Queue
import socket
import time
timeout = 1.0

def check_port(host: str, port: int, results: Queue):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
    result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))
    if result == 0:
        results.put(port)
    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    host = "localhost"
    results = Queue()
    for port in range(80, 100):
        check_port(host, port, results)
    while not results.empty():
        print("Port {0} is open".format(results.get()))
    print("Completed scan in {0} seconds".format(time.time() - start))
```

If `host == 'localhost'`, then this script works very quickly (all ports (form 1 to 65535) checked for about 1.5 secs!), moreover, the duration of the timeout does not play any role.

If I set the host "8.8.8.8" or some other external one, then the script execution time looks correct. For example, checking ports from 440 to 444 with `timeout == 1` on 8.8.8.8 takes about 4 secs.

Why is checking the availability of local ports so fast? (I use Ubuntu if it's important)

Comment: (1) Why do you care that it's faster than expected? (2) Why do you want to check the availabiility of local ports in the first place? There is no programmatic need for this.

Comment: @user207421 of cource, there is no programmatic need for this! I wrote that it's example from the book. I'm just wondering why the timeout value does not affect the script execution time when checking local ports. I guess this question is more about the operating system than programming.

Comment: That's one answer at best to two questions. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @user207421 I don't have any problems about this. I just want to understand why checking local and remote ports happens differently (e.g. timeout).

Comment: Because the network is and isn't involved, respectively. But if you're 'checking the availability of local ports', which is what it says in your question, *my* question remains 'why'? You don't need this, and you shouldn't do it this way, so any question as to how it behaves is irrelevant. It continues to baffle me why authors put pointless code into their books.

Answer (score 0):

In case of localhost the connection attempt gets immediately rejected, so timeout is not reached. In the case of the remote host it probably just drops the packets instead of rejecting (depends on firewall and host configuration), so it will run into timeout.